# Windows 7 Event Viewer - Save logs in real-time

Tags: windows-7, logging, event-viewer, real-time, deep-freeze

I recently changed event viewer to save logs to an external drive then restarted my computer.

It's working fine, however, the logs aren't being written in real time.

When I open Event Viewer, it shows logs up until a minute ago.

When I look in the external drive where the logs are now being written, it says the file was last modified a day ago.

It seems like the logs in my external drive are only being written when I turn off my computer, or do something major like install a program.

The reason I'm logging externally is because my computer won't sleep sometimes and I have to restart it. I use Faronics DeepFreeze so any log written right before the time of the error on C: will be erased on restart (and my screen is black, so I can't see the logs).

I don't want to thaw my computer then wait for the next error - it could take days or weeks, who knows.. I just want real-time logs written externally so I can troubleshoot on restart.

Any suggestions?

Cheers.